# object composition in PDDL

Tags: pddl

I'm very new to `PDDL` and stumbling into something basic.

The object model is something along the line of:

- Object A has multiple numeric properties: Object B is a collection of Object A,
- as part of the pre-condition in an action where the parameter passed is Object B, properties of all Object A's (that are contained in Object B) need to satisfy certain criteria.

Using **functions**, I can define numeric properties of Object A, but I don't know how to capture "Object B is a collection of Object A"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it adheres to your problem specification, but couldn't you just define a predicate `is_part_of(?x - ObjectA ?y - ObjectB)` to define this property?

Then in the precondition you can use a `forall` quantifier on all `objectA`. In the `forall` body state that when the predicate is true, the objects have to satisfy the criteria. Note that PDDL has the `when` keyword that makes this easy. Otherwise you could encode this as just a simple `or` by encoding the alternative.